# Naive bayes: Log odds derivation

Tags: probability, statistics, naive-bayes

How does one go from line 17 to 18 in the below picture? i.e. conversion to linear function of the input variable.

[image]

Source: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/cs769/nb.pdf

Comment: The reasoning from step 17 to step 18 is the same as the reasoning that leads equation 3 to equation 6, in the referenced document.

Comment: It is probably natural that questions which one cannot understand without consulting offsite material should garner answers/comments which one cannot understand without consulting offsite material.

Answer (score 3):

The question was: Why is the following true?
$$
\log p(y = 1 | x) - \log p(y = 0 | x) = (\log \theta_1 - \log \theta_0)^T x + (\log p(y = 1) - \log p(y = 0))
$$

---

From the problem statement, we are given the distribution of the output $x$, given the input $y$. It is:
$$
p (x | y) = \textrm{const}\cdot\prod_{w = 1}^{v} \theta_{y_w}^{c_w}.
$$
From the problem statement, 
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_v\end{bmatrix}^T.
$$
Then, notice that $x,\theta_y \in \mathbb{R}^v$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log p(x | y) & = \log \textrm{const} + \log \prod_{w = 1}^{v} \theta_{y_w}^{c)w} \\
& = \log \textrm{const} + \sum_{w = 1}^{v} \log \theta_{y_w}^{c_w} \\
& = \log \textrm{const} + \sum_{w = 1}^{v} c_w \log \theta_{y_w} \\
& = \log \textrm{const} + \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_v \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \log \theta_{y_1} \\ \log \theta_{y_2} \\ \vdots \\ \log \theta_{y_v}\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \log \textrm{const} + x^T \log \theta_y \\
& = \log \textrm{const} + [\log \theta_y]^T x
\end{aligned}
$$
We have used the substitution:
$$
\log \left(\begin{bmatrix} \theta_{y_1} \\ \theta_{y_2} \\ \vdots \\ \theta_{y_v}\end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} \log \theta_{y_1} \\ \log \theta_{y_2} \\ \vdots \\ \log\theta_{y_v}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then,
$$
\log p(x | y = i) = \log \textrm{const} + [\log \theta_i]^T x.
$$
My understanding is if $y$ is denoted as $0$ or $1$, then the entire vector of parameters $\theta_y$ changes to some pre-determined and known vector corresponding to a $0$ state or $1$ state.

Now, going back to the first line of the question,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log p(y = 1 | x) - \log p(y = 0 | x) & = \log \frac{p(y = 1 | x)}{p(y = 0 | x)} \\
& = \log \left(\frac{\frac{p(y = 1 , x)}{p(x)}} {\frac{p(y = 0 , x)}{p(x)}}\right)\\
& = \log \frac{p(y = 1 , x)}{p(y = 0 , x)} \\
& = \log \frac{p(x | y = 1)\cdot p(y = 1)}{p(x | y = 0)\cdot p(y = 0)} \\
& = \log \frac{p(x | y = 1)}{p(x | y = 0)} + \log \frac{p(y = 1)}{p(y = 0)} \\
& = \log p(x | y = 1) - \log p(x | y = 0) + \log p(y = 1) - \log p(y = 0) \\
& = \log \textrm{const} + [\log \theta_1]^T x - \log \textrm{const} - [\log \theta_0]^T x + \log p(y = 1) - \log p(y = 0) \\
& = ([\log \theta_1]^T - [\log \theta_0]^T)x + \log p(y = 1) - \log p(y = 0) \\
& = (\log \theta_1 - \log \theta_0)^T x + \log p(y = 1) - \log p(y = 0)
\end{aligned}
$$